# The form of $w \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ satisfying $\beta(w)=w$, $\beta$ an involution on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, birational-geometry, involutions

**The symmetric case:**

Let $w \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$, and write $w=\frac{u}{v}$, where $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Let $\beta: (x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$; $\beta$ is an involution (= an automorphism of order two) on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, and hence an involution on $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Assume that $\beta(w)=w$.

> Is it possible to find the 'exact' form of $w$?

**My answer:** Write $u=s+k$ and $v=s'+k'$, where $s,s' \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$ and $k,k' \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are skew-symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$.

Observe that it is easy to find the general form of a symmetric element w.r.t. $\beta$: 
$a_{2n}y^{2n}+\cdots+a_{2}y^2+a_0$, where $a_{2i} \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.
Similarly, the general form of a skew-symmetric element w.r.t. $\beta$: 
$b_{2m+1}y^{2m+1}+\cdots+b_{3}y^3+b_1y$, where $b_{2j+1} \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Now, $\beta(w)=w$ means that $\frac{s-k}{s'-k'}=\frac{s+k}{s'+k'}$, and then after a direct calculation we obtain $ks'=sk'$, equivalently, $\frac{k}{k'}=\frac{s}{s'}$.
Then if we write $\mathbb{C}(x,y) \ni c:=\frac{k}{k'}=\frac{s}{s'}$, we get
$u=s+k=cs'+ck'=c(s'+k')=cv$, so $w=\frac{u}{v}=\frac{cv}{v}=c=\frac{k}{k'}=\frac{s}{s'}$.

Therefore, we obtained that $w$ must be a quotient of two symmetric polynomials (w.r.t. $\beta$) or 
$w$ must be a quotient of two skew-symmetric polynomials (w.r.t. $\beta$).

Actually, a skew-symmetric element is a multiple of $y$ by a symmetric element, so 'the reduced form' of $w$ is as a quotient of two symmetric polynomials.
('reduced form' to symmetric and skew-symmetric elements, but not reduced to irreducible factors).

Am I right?

Thank you very much!

---

**The skew-symmetric case:**

Let $w \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$, and write $w=\frac{u}{v}$, where $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Let $\beta: (x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$; $\beta$ is an involution (= an automorphism of order two) on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, and hence an involution on $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Assume that $\beta(w)=-w$.

> Is it possible to find the 'exact' form of $w$?

**My answer:** Write $u=s+k$ and $v=s'+k'$, where $s,s' \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$ and $k,k' \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are skew-symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$.

Now, $\beta(w)=-w$ means that $\frac{s-k}{s'-k'}=-\frac{s+k}{s'+k'}$, and then after a direct calculation we obtain $ss'=kk'$, equivalently, $\frac{s}{k'}=\frac{k}{s'}$.
Then if we write $\mathbb{C}(x,y) \ni c:=\frac{s}{k'}=\frac{k}{s'}$, we get
$u=s+k=ck'+cs'=c(k'+s')=cv$, so $w=\frac{u}{v}=\frac{cv}{v}=c=\frac{s}{k'}=\frac{k}{s'}$.

Therefore, we obtained that $w$ must be a quotient of a symmetric polynomial with a skew-symmetric polynomial, or vice versa.

Since $k$ is skew-symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$, it has the form $k=s''y$ for some symmetric $s''$. Therefore, $w=\frac{k}{s'}$ becomes $w=\frac{s''y}{s'}=\frac{s''}{s'}y$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @AlanMuniz, thank you. Please, do you think that more that can be said? I am not sure if I know exactly what I am looking for; any ideas are welcome. Of course a similar (but not identical) result holds when $\beta(\tilde{w})=-\tilde{w}$.

Comment: You will only get that $w$ is the quotient of polynomials in $(x,y^2)$, nothing more.

Comment: @AlanMuniz, thank you. I will now think of the skew-symmetric case, namely, $\beta(\tilde{w})=-\tilde{w}$, and perhaps add this case to my question. Please do not let me know what you think before the edit.

Comment: So for symmetric $w$ we get that $w \in \mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$ and for skew-symmetric $w$ we just get that $w \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ (which is already known and trivial). The forms $w=\frac{s}{s'}$ and $w=\frac{s''}{s'}y$ are quite nice (at least in my opinion).

Comment: If you require that numerator and denominator do not share a common factor then  it may happen that $w = \dfrac{s}{ys'}$ with $s$ and $s'$ "symmetric".

Comment: Thank you. If I am not wrong, there are two cases (in the skew-symmetric case): $w=\frac{s}{k'}=\frac{s}{s'''y}=\frac{s}{s'''}\frac{1}{y}$ (as you mentioned)  or $w=\frac{k}{s'}=\frac{s''y}{s'}=\frac{s''}{s'}y$. I have not yet thought about requiring relatively prime numerator and denominator.

Comment: Oh, you probably meant, for example, $w=\frac{1}{y}$ which only has this form in the reduced form (or $w=\frac{y}{y^2}=\frac{1}{y^2}y$ in a non-reduced form).